# Empty line on a slide in Latex Beamer

Tags: latex, beamer

I am using Latex Beamer for creating a presentation.

On one slide I have

```
\frame
{
  \frametitle{fdjsljklfdjs}
  What is fdjsljklfdjs
  \begin{itemize}
  \item item one
  \item item one
  \end{itemize}

  Why do we want to know it
  \begin{itemize}
  \item item one
  \item item one
  \item item three
  \end{itemize}
}
```

I would like to have space between the first itemize block and the second question. However, if I try `\\` or `\newline`, I get a pdflatex parsing error:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

How can I get an emtpy line?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `\vspace`, e.g.

```
\vspace{1in}
```

for a one inch vertical space. If you want it to be equal to the normal distance between two lines, use the length `\baselineskip`.

Comment: The \baselineskip does not work for me, but the \vspace{} command does! Thanks!

Comment: Do you also know what the reason is that \\ and \newline don't work?

Comment: I don't know more than what can be read from the error message. As I understand it (I've seen this message a few times myself), \\ and \newline just break an existing line, but there is no line to break before you put some content on it and a new line has just been created for you after the itemize block. I might be totally wrong in that interpretation, but that's my guess anyway.

Comment: @Peter: `\baselineskip` is a length. To use it with `\vspace` you have to write `\vspace{\baselineskip}`.